# How to fix Mat modules in Angular

Tags: angular

I was trying to create a web using MatButtons and other Mat modules, but I got a lot of errors. I tried several things like changing the version of TypeScript but it didn't help. Can you please help me? thanks

Errors (when typing ng serve to node.js):
https://prnt.sc/12xa686

and

https://prnt.sc/12xa7wl

and

https://prnt.sc/12xa9n2

Code in Visual Studio Code:

login.component.html:

```
<div>
    <mat-card>
        <form>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder='Username'>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type='password' placeholder='Password'>
          </mat-form-field>
        </form>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'savWeb';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/Button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Also there is one error but I've already changed it so I don't really know why it keeps saying it.

https://prnt.sc/12xastg

and this is what happens when I open the web:
https://prnt.sc/12xawll

Comment: @MagentaBloabner will reply to potential suggestions, he is a collaborator

Comment: The last image happen because the app failed do load/compile.  The second last, about decorators, keep happening on VSCode, just ignore. The other ones, I only saw something similar when I tried to install Material on a online editor. But the most recent Material update, ver. 12.0.0 had a ";" typo breaking the internal modules. Could you show us, you package.json, where its said your Material version installed?

Comment: What version of Angular and what version of Angular Material are you using?

Comment: Versions are here https://prnt.sc/12xdzqp or here https://prnt.sc/12xegqq as mentioned in first answer of my collaborator

Comment: @Rafael de Castro Do you have any other idea according to the Angular versions?

Comment: @Paulus141 I confirmed here, your Angular material version is the problematic 12.0.0. You can see on the first pic, on the @angular/material: "^12.0.0".

Comment: To change, replace the "^12.0.0" with "11.2.12". Save the file, then run thi npm install on the project folder. Try this and come back

Comment: @rafaeldecastro https://prnt.sc/12ybgpr and https://prnt.sc/12ybh64